# Data is not getting appended for the second time

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I want to display data on click of an icon. The data is shown for the first time, but it is not showing for the second time. I am appending data to the `$('body')` element.

my view.js.html.erb is

```
$(".view-schemes").live('click', function(e) {
    var schemes_url = "<%= show_schemes_products_path %>";
    var p_id = $(this).attr('id');
    get_data(schemes_url, { id: p_id }, function(data) {
      $('body').append(data);
    },"html");
  });
```

And I am getting data for the second time, but data is not appended to the body. Is there any solution or an alternate way of writing this query?

Comment: why your file name is like `view.js.html.erb`? can you `alert(data)` on each click?

Comment: what version of jquery to you use. it's long time ago that i've seen `.live`

Answer (score 1):

Try to create new div with `id="appended_div"` inside `body`.
and append data in the appended div every time on click of `.view-schemes`. 
After changes your JS code will be as:

```
$(".view-schemes").live('click', function(e) {
    var schemes_url = "<%= show_schemes_products_path %>";
    var p_id = $(this).attr('id');
    get_data(schemes_url, { id: p_id }, function(data) {
      $('#appended_div').empty();
      $('#appended_div').append(data);
    },"html");
  });
```

Hope this resolves your issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

first of all use a current version of jQuery.

```
$(".view-schemes").live('click', function(e) {
...
```

could be changed to catch a element more flexible

```
$('body').on('click', '.view-schemes', function(e) {
...
```

this helps when a element will be added after the page is loaded.